# How to find out elements having the same content in a list?

Tags: python, list

A list as below, contains some elements have the same content.

For example, "A120 v.s. B127" and "B127 v.s. A120" are naturally have the same content, so only "B127 v.s. A120" is considered as a duplicate in this case.

I want to find out which are the duplicates:

```
a_list = [

"A120 v.s. B127",
"A125 v.s. B105",
"A122 v.s. B141",
"A150 v.s. B100",
"A147 v.s. B141",
"B127 v.s. A120",
"B100 v.s. A150"

]

for a in a_list:
    flip = a.split(' v.s. ')[1] + " v.s. " + a.split(' v.s. ')[0]
    if flip in a_list:
        print a + " is a duplicate."
```

However the code marks more (also the first occurrence) duplicates:

```
A120 v.s. B127 is a duplicate.
A150 v.s. B100 is a duplicate.
B127 v.s. A120 is a duplicate.
B100 v.s. A150 is a duplicate.
```

What's the way to only output the actual duplicates, like?

```
B127 v.s. A120 is a duplicate of A120 v.s. B127.
B100 v.s. A150 is a duplicate of A150 v.s. B100
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short solution with *hashable* dict keys:

```
a_list = [
    "A120 v.s. B127", "A125 v.s. B105", "A122 v.s. B141",
    "A150 v.s. B100", "A147 v.s. B141", "B127 v.s. A120",
    "B100 v.s. A150"
]

d = {}
for s in a_list:
    items = tuple(sorted(s.split()))
    if items in d:
        print(s, 'is a duplicate of', d[items])
    else:
        d[items] = s
```

The output:

```
B127 v.s. A120 is a duplicate of A120 v.s. B127
B100 v.s. A150 is a duplicate of A150 v.s. B100
```

Comment: Yeah this is the best and should be the accepted answer, I was going to post the same O(N) solution with the power of HashMap (Python dictionary) @prashant rana

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal i just made that solution in simplist way for OP  understandablity , this is good solution, using tuple, sorted is little costly though

Comment: What I actually wanted was just a comparision operation on 0th and 2nd index after split, that was the best implementation that one could come up with @prashantrana something like `item = s.split()` 

`items = (item[0] + item[2] if item[0] < item[1] else item[2]+item[0])`

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal don't know oabout your problem, as this i s  mark problem, if any solution help u its good

Answer (score 3):

```
a_list = [

"A120 v.s. B127",
"A125 v.s. B105",
"A122 v.s. B141",
"A150 v.s. B100",
"A147 v.s. B141",
"B127 v.s. A120",
"B100 v.s. A150"
]
tmp=[]
for v,i in enumerate(a_list):
    if v not in tmp:
        var =' '.join(i.split()[::-1])
        if var in a_list:
            tmp.append(a_list.index(var))

            print('{} is duplicate of {}'.format(i, var))
```

output

```
A120 v.s. B127 is duplicate of B127 v.s. A120
A150 v.s. B100 is duplicate of B100 v.s. A150
```

Comment: marvelous solution! thank you for sharing the way of thinking!

Answer (score 2):

you can use a `set` for fast lookup, and a sorted tuple to know if something is a duplicate regardless of order:

```py
a_list = [
"A120 v.s. B127",
"A125 v.s. B105",
"A122 v.s. B141",
"A150 v.s. B100",
"A147 v.s. B141",
"B127 v.s. A120",
"B100 v.s. A150"
]

seen_set = set()

for line in a_list:
    pair = line.split(' v.s. ')
    sorted_pair = tuple(sorted(pair))
    if sorted_pair in seen_set:
        print('{} is a duplicate of {}'.format(' v.s. '.join(pair), ' v.s. '.join(pair[::-1])))
    seen_set.add(sorted_pair)
```

Output:

```
B127 v.s. A120 is a duplicate of A120 v.s. B127
B100 v.s. A150 is a duplicate of A150 v.s. B100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

```
a_list = [
"A120 v.s. B127",
"A125 v.s. B105",
"A122 v.s. B141",
"A150 v.s. B100",
"A147 v.s. B141",
"B127 v.s. A120",
"B100 v.s. A150"
]

for a in a_list:
    flip = a.split(' v.s. ')[1] + " v.s. " + a.split(' v.s. ')[0]
    if flip in a_list:
        print(flip + " is a duplicate of " + a)
        del a_list[a_list.index(flip)]
```

Output:

```
B127 v.s. A120 is a duplicate of A120 v.s. B127
B100 v.s. A150 is a duplicate of A150 v.s. B100
```

Comment: this' a very interesting solution. Only 1 more line to add to achieve the goal. Why it received a down vote?

Comment: @MarkK don't know why :(

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi maybe it's because you were not able to use bankai so soon, only work with the own  strength only :P

Comment: @Zaraki Kenpachi, hope you don't mind I choose the most voted for the answer. But your answer opens a new door of learning. :)

Comment: @MarkK no problem, enjoy :)